# Unable to add registry in Anchore running on kubernetes

Tags: security, containers, amazon-eks, scanning

I'm trying to add ECR registry in anchore that is setup in kubernetes. I created an achore-cli pod and tried to execute the below command

```
anchore-cli registry add /
               1234567890.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com /
               awsauto /
               awsauto /
               --registry-type=awsecr
```

and I got the following output,

```
Error: 'awsauto' is not enabled in service configuration
HTTP Code: 406
Detail: {'error_codes': []}
```

I configured IAM Role via service account with `AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly` policy. Can someone help me with this?